# Sharepoint 2010 Calendar Webpart View Powershell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, calendar

On the main page of a basic team site template I have a calendar webpart and its view by default is based upon the Calendar list calendar view.  My issue is that after applying a new calendar overlay on the calendar list, the main page view does not automatically update to reflect this change.  I have to instead edit the webpart, select the calendar view (which is what is currently being used by default) and apply that change.  I am attempting to accomplish this task in powershell with no luck.

The code I was attemping to use is:

```
$web = get-spweb "http://portal/site/testsite1"
$file = $web.getfile("default.aspx")
$manager = $file.getlimitedwebpartmanager([System.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.personalizationscope]::shared)
$manager.webparts | format-list title, ID

$wp = $manager.webparts["GUID_HERE"]
$doclib = $web.lists["Calendar"]
$view = $doclib.Views["Calendar"]

$wp.ViewGuid = $view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper()
$manager.SaveChanges($wp)
```

Unfortunately this has not been effective in updating the view to reflect the current overlays being applied in the calendar view and so only manual intervention has been working.  Is there some powershell code I can use to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is correct but in details there is an error. You should not rely upon ViewGuid. Have a look at [this article](http://spblog.net/post/2011/04/26/Changing-default-view-for-ListViewWebPart-programmatically.aspx). You may find it helpful. Then convert the .NET code to PowerShell scripts and you will have what you need. Even better suggestion is to put this code into and event receiver into the event that fires on the update of the list.